# Jetbrains Rider: [MSB4057] The target "build" does not exist in the project

Tags: asp.net-core, jetbrains-ide, rider

When I create solution in Jetbrains Rider EAP 21 I get "*(with missing packages)*" error in Solution Explorer window.

Then, I try to build project and get **[MSB4057]** error.

[image]

Despite this, I can run the project through Terminal:

```
dotnet restore
dotnet build
```

... and get following information:

```
Hosting environment: Production
Content root path: *path*
Now listening on: http://localhost:5000
Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
```

dotnet --info command result:

```
.NET Command Line Tools (1.0.3)

Product Information:
 Version:            1.0.3
 Commit SHA-1 hash:  37224c9917

Runtime Environment:
 OS Name:     Mac OS X
 OS Version:  10.12
 OS Platform: Darwin
 RID:         osx.10.12-x64
 Base Path:   /usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk/1.0.3
```

Comment: Rider settings reset to defaults

Comment: I suppose it's a bug in Rider, could you send us logs? Help -> Show Log In...

Comment: Also you can run Rider in internal mode [https://rider-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/207327910], create an .net core application and invoke "reload project and show logs" from solution explorer context menu. It also can contain some useful diagnostic =)

Answer (score 3):

I've resolved a similar problem by changing the MSBuild version in Settings > Build, Execution, Deployment > Toolset and Build > Use MSBuild version.

I've selected the MSBuild located in the Rider install directory.

Answer (score 0):

I recently started receiving such errors in many of my projects. Initially I believed that it was because of Rider's version and rolled back, but instead, it was a problem with the latest MSBuild from the Visual Studio Installation (I use Windows).

The solution for me was to go to `File | Settings | Build, Execution, Deployment | Toolset and Build` and then tweak the `Use MSBuild` setting. By default, Rider used the MSBuild that was installed alongside Visual Studio. I changed it to use the MSBuild version installed with Rider instead and the problem went away. The same solution is also discussed in [Jebtrains's bug tracking system](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RIDER-63446#focus=Comments-27-4934840.0-0)

Answer (score -1):

The problem was resolved by installing new version of **Mono** from [official site](http://www.mono-project.com/download/)

Comment: Updated to a latest version, restarted machine & still have the problem